Seamless AOAG failover with DTC?
With SQL Server 2017 and higher, can using "Per Database DTC Support" help mitigate disruptions to connected applications or will the queries running on Node1 at time of failover to Node2 error out? Is there any way to gracefully "hand off" running transactions from node to node?

No, a session, query or transaction wont survive a fail-over.
